# Minikube cluster not working correctly on windows - web app not loading

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm trying to develop a simple cluster using minikube on my local machine.
Minikube is running on top of docker as a container.
I was unable create image and up and run containers. for that, i upload my-docker-image to docker hub and pull from it. The cluster is created but the ip address not showing anything.
What am i done wrong.
My app.js

```
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`));`
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-node-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-node-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: nodePort

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-node-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-node-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-node-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-node-app
          image: hub-acc/my-node-app:latest
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-node-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

I tried following steps.
`docker tag my-node-app:latest name/my-node-app:latest`
`docker push name/my-node-app:latest`
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
`minikube start`
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
`minikube service my-node-app-service --url`

**The open link not showing anything
`kubectl get services`
CLUSTER-IP is given but EXTERNAL-IP  is 
I tried Types - NodePort / LoadBalancer / ClusterIP. But unable up and run the application.

Thank you for your attention.

kubectl get services
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
my-node-app-service           NodePort       10.107.246.196        80:32720/TCP     9h

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be complex, and debugging also need be complex. You are checking last point of your application - IP address of outgoing traffic. You need to debug all, one by one.

- Pod is working? Check status. Run port forward to see if it is working.
- Service is working? Cluster IP - this is IP address visible only inside cluster resources, e.g. from other Pod. External IP - this is IP address visible outside cluster, e.g. other computers.
- Firewall on your computer? Wrong network interface?
- On which network interfaces your cluster is listening? Localhost? Ethernet?